# Binding paragraph value to hidden input in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jQuery function to calculate the `net` weight by using `gross` weight minus `tare` weight. It looks like this and it is working:

```
    $(".sub").focusout(function () {
        $("#net").html('');
        var gross = $("#gross").val();
        var tare = $("#tare").val();
        var net = (gross - tare);
        $("#net").html(Math.round(net * 1000) / 1000);
    });
```

And my html currently looks like this:

```
<input type='number' name='gross' id='gross' class='sub' />
<input type='number' step="any" name='tare' id='tare' class='sub' />
<p id='net' class='sub1'></p>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenNet" value=${net}/>
```

Notice the last line of the html I have a hidden `input` called `hiddenNet` and what I am trying to do here is bind the value of `net` with it. In other words, whenever `p` gets a net weight value based on the `gross` and `tare`, I want the value gets passed to `hiddenNet`. But what I am currently not getting any value, what did I do wrong?

Comment: You using any templating?

Comment: @Tushar no, just plain javascript and jQuery.

Comment: Then you have to set the value by yourself, using `{net}` won't update the value dynamically

Comment: I agree with Tushar, what lead you to think `${net}` would be interpreted as "the value of the net variable" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you simply set the value of your hidden field

```js
$(".sub").focusout(function() {
  $("#net").html('');
  var gross = $("#gross").val();
  var tare = $("#tare").val();
  var net = (gross - tare);
  $("#net").html(Math.round(net * 1000) / 1000);
  $("input[name=hiddenNet]").val($("#net").html());
});
```

```html
<input type='number' name='gross' id='gross' class='sub' />
<input type='number' step="any" name='tare' id='tare' class='sub' />
<p id='net' class='sub1'></p>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenNet" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using jQuery, the bind will not work. You need to set the value vía jQuery, check the line I added at last.

```
$(".sub").focusout(function () {
    $("#net").html('');
    var gross = $("#gross").val();
    var tare = $("#tare").val();
    var net = (gross - tare);
    $("#net").html(Math.round(net * 1000) / 1000);
    $("input[name='hiddenNet']").val(net);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is not a front-end templating framework like angularJS, you need to change the value of `[name="hiddenNet"]` after an event has been triggered.

You need to add something along the line of `$('input[name="hiddenNet"]').val(net);` to your function for the value to be updated correctly.

And if I you was would I would make my `net` variable contain the right value right away:

```
var net = Math.round((gross - tare) * 1000 / 1000);
```